# On interacting QFTs with two masses $m$ and $M>2m$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, s-matrix-theory, nuclear-physics

[hep-th/0412302v2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0412302.pdf) is an interesting paper by Shvedov about rigorous semiclassical covariant QFT. Shvedov talks on p.27 and p.30 about ''well-known'' properties of a putative interacting QFT with two masses $m$ and $M>2m$, which gives rise to an unstable particle that decays into two particles of mass $m$, with a known (presumably at 1-loop accuracy) decay rate. This is interesting since the standard nonrigorous textbook LSZ approach would posit instead asymptotic states of mass $m$ and $M$, needed to create the noninteracting Fock space, which then serves as asymptotic state space. Intuitively, the more massive particle is embedded into the continuum of the less massive field theory, hence the interaction should turn it into a resonance according to nonrelativistic wisdom.

I'd like to see what is actually in the literature. But Shvedov gives no references. Where can I find details about the derivation of the statements he called ''well-known''?

Comment: You can try lecture 17 of "Lectures of Sidney Coleman on QFT" where he discussed  unstable particles in that context